# html icon show in firefox but cannot showed in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
link REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="/images/greenTheme/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"
```

the above code work in firefox but doesnt work in IE, how to make it work in IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<link href='/path/to/favicon.ico' rel='icon' type='image/vnd.microsoft.icon'/>
```

Also if you have a 57x57 pixel PNG for an iPhone

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

•Make sure, the path to the favicon in the header of your page is absolute, not relative.

•Delete your temporary internet files. If the folder with temporary files has reached its maximum, the favicon may not be used.
.

Comment: it's the cache problem. but clear cache doesnt seem to work. it work the next day after i restar pc

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type bit to

```
type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
```